# How to read html from a webpage using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I've ben trying for several hours now to get this to work...

Ive made a Xamarin Forms PCL project where I've been trying to read the html of a webpage.

This is my most recent attempt:

//The method i call to read in the webpage

```
async Task<String> GetWebContent() 
   {

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        return await httpClient.GetStringAsync ("http://www.google.se");
    }
```

I then call this method like this:

```
string html = await GetWebContent();
DisplayAlert("alert", html, "ok");
```

I just try to display the html of the webpage to see that it works, but it always returns blank. Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Also I've added these two nugetpackages: 
Microsoft.Bcl.Async, which adds async/await support to PCLs.
Microsoft.Net.Http, which adds HttpClient support to PCLs.

Comment: The method signature should be Task<string>. Is it Task or is it just a formatting issue with the site?

Comment: No it just that it comes back with nothing, I want the html from the page.. but it gives me an empty string

Comment: Managed to solve this using dependency service

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this one a try and see if it throws an exception of any kind? I tested this on a device and it seems to work just fine.

```
    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {   
        var button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Click to display web page",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };

        var page = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = button
        };

        button.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var webPage = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.se"));
                    await page.DisplayAlert("alert", webPage, "ok", "cancel");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            };



        return page;
    }
```

Comment: For me that dosent display the HTML of the webpage? Its still just shows a blank

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Everything seems fine. Are you sure that you've provided all the permissions?